# How frontend instance hours calculated on Google app engine. How can we Reduce frontend instance hours inJAVA

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am working on GWT java project using Google app engine engine. I deployed my app on Google app engine its free instance four finished early.  So i want to know how frontend instance hours are calculated.Why instance hours increase high.

Any help 
thanks in advance

Comment: show us specific questions. get a general overview on the official appengine help.

Answer (score 0):

please see the section "Instance Hours" at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas